# PHP autoloading namespace on xampp

Tags: php, xampp, namespaces, autoload

I am trying to autoload php class under namespace on xampp. But for some reason it cannot find class under its absolute path.

here is my autoloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $className). '.php');
})
```

here is my class

```
namespace app\admin\modules\smartForm;
class smartForm {
/* Class logic*/
}
```

This is my file system:

[image: This is my file system]

This i error i am getting:

**Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/app/admin/modules/smartForm/smartForm.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\smartfrom\app\system\autoLoader.php on line 3**

Comment: It's not in the `admin` folder.  Try `app\modules\smartForm` maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like after 3 days i finally figure it out.

Instead of going trought absolute path you can choose relative path from autoloader file.

here is final include:

```
  include_once(__DIR__.'\..\\'.$className.'.php');
```